# Very strange issue on setting the alarm

Tags: java, android, android-intent, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I have set three repeating daily alarms on 12：00，16：00 and 20：00. 
But I found that the first alarm would not activate on time, but instead go off 11：59：34, 12：00：12 and 12：00:56.

I don't know why this would happen, and I have read many documents, no one gives me an answer.
Please help me!

Here is my code:

```
//Set the Calendar
Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

//set PendingIntent
Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
alarmIntent.putExtra("alarmType", 3);
PendingIntent pendingIntentMoring = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 51, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
PendingIntent pendingIntentAfternoon = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 52, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
PendingIntent pendingIntentEvening = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 53, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

//clear the alarm manager before set the new alarm
managerMorning.cancel(pendingIntentMoring);
managerAfternoon.cancel(pendingIntentAfternoon);
managerEvening.cancel(pendingIntentEvening);


//set new alarm
managerMorning.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal1.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntentMoring);
managerAfternoon.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal2.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntentAfternoon);
managerEvening.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal3.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntentEvening);

//set Receiver
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent myMessageintent = new Intent(context, UpDateDiaryMessage.class);
    myMessageintent.putExtra("alarmType", 3);
    context.startService(myMessageintent);
}
```

I've tested it many times.
I can't get the alarm to activate 12:00:00, but I got two or three alarms around 12:00:00.
I don't know why it sometimes works and sometimes not.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein I think this has to be posted as an answer. :)

Comment: @Sufian Advice accepted.

Comment: Post your code where you initialize the `Calendar` objects.

Comment: Thanx mate, you save me!!!! let me have a look the official document T_T carefully.

Comment: I have add the Calendar object.

Answer (score 2):

As per the [official docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html):

> **Note:** Beginning with API 19 ([`KITKAT`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html#KITKAT)) alarm delivery is inexact: the OS
>   will shift alarms in order to minimize wakeups and battery use. There
>   are new APIs to support applications which need strict delivery
>   guarantees; see [`setWindow(int, long, long, PendingIntent)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setWindow%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) and
>   [`setExact(int, long, PendingIntent)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setExact%28int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29). Applications whose
>   `targetSdkVersion` is earlier than API 19 will continue to see the
>   previous behavior in which all alarms are delivered exactly when
>   requested.

Comment: Thanx mate, you save me!!!! let me have a look the official document T_T carefully

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell

- for API < 19 you can use `set()` method. For these APIs this will set an exact alarm
- for 19 <= API < 23 you should use `setExact()` to set exact alarms, and `set()` to set inexact alarms
- for API = 23, Doze mode was also introduced, so in addition if you also want your alarm to go off even when the phone is in Doze mode, you should use `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()` method instead.

Comment: Yes. I should notice the API version and to use the proper method. Thank you man.  :)